# iMac's Built-in microphone doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: audio, imac, bootcamp, windows, microphone

I have an iMac on which i have installed Windows 7 32-bit. I have used Bootcamp version 4.0.4033.  I have done it with the Apple tech support person. My built-in microphone doesn't work in Windows. I set it up correctly, according to specs in the Windows help. I realized that it doesn't work when I tried using Skype.
Could you please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your microphone works fine under OSX?

Did you download and install the bootcamp drivers for Windows 7?

Windows needs the driver installed to "see" the microphone and access it.

Can you see the microphone in the device manager?

Did you check the input levels for the microphone in Windows audio setup control panel? The gain may need to be adjusted.